# Django csrf in ajax POST (csrf cookie not set until {{csrf}} used)

Tags: python, ajax, django, cookies, csrf

My django application uses ajax to add an item to shopping cart. The ajax request method is POST, and i enable request header via js:

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is, that i send request not from the form, but just using a button and onClick event, so i do not use a {{ csrf }} in the template. So, the cookie is not set, until i visit another page (for example, login page). Should i use a form (it is not a very good idea, because i have many items on one page, and form with csrf token is created for each one), or there is a way to set csrf cookie manually, if it is not set? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always just drop a `{% csrf_token %}` hidden form field anywhere in your template and pick it up by name if the cookie isn't set yet. You don't have to put it inside a form tag to be valid HTML.

Just change your logic to something like:

```
var csrftoken == getCookie('csrftoken') || $(":input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
```

That of course depends on what `getCookie` returns.

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty easy. I used input, and jqery selector to get value. No need in getCookie() now.